# Cannot resolve 'hystrix.command'

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, hystrix

application.yml cannot recognize hystrix.command. The corresponding Maven Dependency is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I couldn't find any clue about why hystrix.command doesn't work. Spring Boot version is 2.6.2

Comment: Hystrix support was removed in spring cloud 2020.0 and is not compatible with boot 2.4+